# Full images from UIPageViewController not showing up in my iOS 8 project

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, ios-simulator

I have been trying to create a simple iOS app using the UIPageViewController, and everything seems to be working fine...except my images are completely cut off. Only the top part of my images are shown in the UIPageViewController and after several hours of messing around with different settings, etc. I seem to be getting nowhere. I don't know if this is a problem with my image resolutions or whether it is a problem with the actual placement of the image in the storyboard.

*I will include some screenshots and code below:*

**Just to let you know what the app looks like while running, here are some screenshots. Note the small bar at the bottom are my images and if I swipe, they switch to the other images. The problem is I want my images to be fullscreen but they obviously are not and I do not know why.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        pageController.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        return true
    }
}
```

The code in ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

// line below is where I get the error

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

//end

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var pageTitles: NSArray!
    var pageImages: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "", "", "")
        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "page1", "page2", "page3")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as!
        UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    @IBAction func restartAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController
    {
        if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count))
        {
            return ContentViewController()
        }

        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String

        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc
    }

    // Mark: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        if (index == self.pageTitles.count)
        {
            return nil
        }

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.pageTitles.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

And finally, the code in ContentViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var pageIndex: Int!
    var imageFile: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageFile)
    }
}
```

**Here are all the images I have:**

[image]

**Here is a look at my storyboard**

[image]

**Here is a look at the Content View Controller which includes my UIImageViewer (I think the problem might be with my formatting/use of settings here, but I might be wrong)**

[image]

Comment: My first suggestion would be to make sure you've added Auto Layout constraints to your `UIImageView`.

Comment: How would you do this? I can't seem to find the settings section where you can toggle Auto Layout constraints?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html